# touch and tar from a text file

Tags: files, tar, timestamps

Am trying to zip a certain number of files and am stuck at below point,

```
   ls -lrt /lag/cnn/*/*/*/adb.tar.gz | grep -nri ABC >> sample.txt
```

In sample.txt i got filesNames on which i have to do touch command to extract filesNames that i need to tar.

```
   touch -t '<time>' first & touch -t '<time>' last
```

So my question is , how can i implement this touch in sample.txt to extract what i need based on time and tar those files. Whether touch command
and tar command can be added to the above command using pipe or should i do it separately.

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to achieve? What are you using touch for? What files are you trying to zip?

Comment: @richard I have certain files in the path /lag/cnn/*/*/*/ i need to tar those files which are created between certain time.Am trying to do this from root directory. So far i have got all the files in the path after grep in sample.txt . from the file i have to extract files based on time and tar it.

Comment: `find` is your friend. I will write an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ask `find` to find files within `/lag/cnn` to a maximum depth of 3 of at least so many minutes old. Then using xargs pass them to tar (to zip it).

This works with gnu tools:

```
find /lag/cnn -maxdepth 3 -newermt "2013-12-19 00:00" -o -type f -newermt "2013-12-16 00:00" -print0 | 
xargs -0 tar acf out.tar.gz
```

This should work with other tools.

```
touch -d 2013-12-19 00:00 later-timestamp.temporary
touch -d 2013-12-16 00:00 earlier-timestamp.temporary
find /lag/cnn -maxdepth 3 -newermm later-timestamp.temporary  -o -type f -newermm earlier-timestamp.temporary -print0 | 
xargs -0 tar zcf out.tar.gz
```

Comment: My start time is :201312160000.00 and my End time is:201312190000.00 in the format "yyyymmddhhmm.ss" and i need to extract files between this time. how to use this in the above command.The format can be changed for that time how to use the command.

Comment: Am getting, find: invalid predicate `-max-depth' and tar: invalid option -- a What is the problem?

Comment: I have changed it to -maxdepth but now am getting find: invalid predicate `-newermt'

Comment: Ah you are not using the Gnu versions. For gnu-tar the a is compress based on file extension (change it to z). For find I don't know, the manual says that not all finds support all of the `-newerXY` combinations. You could try `-newermm reference file`, you will have to use touch to create the two reference files somewhere out of the way.